# Is it not secure download anything by torrent clients by server?

Tags: rhel5, security, torrent

I read some thing about torrent , that any one can get our ip while download torrents or peer to peer connections.

Is there any way for secure downloading by torrent clients ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is just the tracker and users of that tracker that gets your IP address. (Unless your client is set up with trackerless support).

But hiding your IP address only keeps your system hidden, not secure. Eventually someone will find your system even if it's not doing anything.

A system should not rely on [security trough obscurity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security_through_obscurity). Instead of wasting energy on trying to hide on the internet it should be spent on making sure your system is secure.

Answer (score 0):

The whole idea behind Bitorrent is that users download the parts of a file they haven't got, from users that do have it therefore to do this they will need to be able to contact you to get the parts of the file you have. You can encrypt your torrent traffic, but this only prevents someone from seeing what you are downloading, not that you are downloading something.

I suggest that if you are looking for a way of downloading something without someone knowing your IP, you need to look at a different method of doing so, or using some sort of proxy. That said, we might ask why you don't want the service you are downloading from to know your IP? Smells like you might be doing something you shouldn't....

Comment: @Sam Cogan, Is it reduce system security level when downloading by torrent in server ? My question is like this.